# iOS 7 - transparent UIView blocking gesture recognizer

Tags: uiview, ios7, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a 2 views as subviews of the main view.

main view
|
|--- view A
|
|--- view B

And I have a button with frame (0, 0, 50, 50) in view A,
and a button with frame (200, 200, 50, 50) in view B.

View A and view B have nil backgroundColor (so they are both transparent).

And all the views have the same frame.

I want to be able to click both buttons, but only the button from view B is clickable.
That was not the case with iOS 6.

Any ideas?

Ugly solution:

I found a solution to my problem, all I have to do is make my view A and view B be a PassThroughUIView, but this is a very ugly solution, I wonder if there is a better one, one that does not involve changing my view's class.

```
@implementation PassThroughUIView

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UIView *v in self.subviews) {
        CGPoint localPoint = [v convertPoint:point fromView:self];
        if (v.alpha > 0.01 && ![v isHidden] && v.userInteractionEnabled && [v pointInside:localPoint withEvent:event])
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: Just check whether any view is overlapping the button , by changing the background colour of the view.

Comment: are you add any gesture recognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer or any)?

Comment: That is the point, view A is overlapping the main view, and view B is overlapping view A (they all have the same size), and I still want that to work.

Comment: Did you managed to find a solution to that problem? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Not a good one =/, but look at the answer I just accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I came up with was subclass the UIView and implement this:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UIView *v in self.subviews) {
        CGPoint localPoint = [v convertPoint:point fromView:self];
        if (v.alpha > 0.01 && ![v isHidden] && v.userInteractionEnabled && [v pointInside:localPoint withEvent:event])
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

This UIView will be a "Pass through view"